# Unique links for affiliates

Tags: drupal

Have started a site but wondering whether anyone had any ideas on how to do the following.

1. Create a page so that people can signup as affiliates and a unique link is provided to each affiliate so that the affiliate can post their unique link onto websites, forums etc in order to encourage membership to my site.
2. Also once people have gone thru a unique link and then signed up as members, how can I track which affiliate delivered the member.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have the person sign up with your site and save their information in the database.  The primary key of their user record in your datbase is unqiue.  You could pad that for security purposes then give that to the user in the url to your signup page.

For instance:  signup.php?referrer=XXXXX-userid-XXXXX  would be the link you give out to the user once they signed up.

When they stick that on their own site and new users click on it, you can use $_GET['referrer'] to get the ID from the URL and then look up which user that belongs to.

Obviously this is a very simple example, but hopefully you get the jist.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, are there any scripts available anywhere that you know of ?

Comment: As far as scripts go, that would be what you would have to build.  A user registration page would be unique to your database and what information about the user you are collecting.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal there's always a good chance someone has already made a module for what you want.  I haven't tried any of these personally, but the [user referral](http://drupal.org/project/referral) module looks promising, and there are several other results if you search the modules on their site for "[referral](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/referral)" or "[affiliate](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/affiliate)."  Even if they're not exactly what you want, existing modules are usually a much better starting place than starting completely from scratch.